# THREE.js Displaying Scene on top of another Scene

Tags: three.js, scene

I have a scene that has 10 cubes in it.
See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gilomer88/tcpwez72/47/

When a user taps on one of the cubes, I want a new “details scene” to pop-open on top of the current "main scene" and have it display just that one cube the user tapped on.
When the user is done examining and playing with the cube they can close the “details scene”,  thereby revealing the original "main scene" - which was really just sitting underneath it this whole time.

I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: scope.domElement.addEventListener is not a function
```

Can't figure out why that's happening.

Note that the fiddle I made is 95% complete - it's just missing this bit of `HTML` you see here:

```
        <canvas id="detailsCanvas"></canvas>
        <div id="renderingSpot"></div>
```

(As soon as I added this HTML - and the CSS - everything started breaking up on me, no matter what I did to try fixing it - so I finally just took it out.)

Either way, I'm basically creating a new `scene` in which to display the "details view", along with a new `renderer`, `OrbitControl`, etc. - and the error occurs on this line:

```
const detailsOrbitController = new OrbitControls(detailsScene.userData.camera, detailsScene.userData.renderingElement);
```

(That line is in my `makeDetailsScene()` function - which you'll see in the fiddle.)

For what its worth, I was following this THREE.js example when I was putting this together: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=mul#webgl_multiple_elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need this extra `<div id="renderingSpot"></div>`. You could also just pass the canvas to the OrbitControls. When I run the following code, I don't get any errors:

```js
detailsScene.userData.renderingElement = document.getElementById("renderingSpot");
const detailsOrbitController = new OrbitControls(detailsScene.userData.camera, detailsScene.userData.renderingElement);
```

I made some changes to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xn19qbf7/ 
(I also made some HTML, CSS, JS additions such that the details view displays on top of the main canvas and that its scene gets rendered.)

I guess your problem was your original assignment with jQuery:

```js
let renderingElement = $("#renderingSpot");
detailsScene.userData.renderingElement = renderingElement;
```

`renderingElement` is still a jQuery object. But OrbitControls doesn't accept a jQuery object. So, you should get the real element:

```js
let renderingElement = $("#renderingSpot");
detailsScene.userData.renderingElement = renderingElement.get(0);
// or as above
detailsScene.userData.renderingElement = document.getElementById("renderingSpot");
```

Comment: Hey I arrived at the same conclusion about the difference between using `jQuery` and good old vanilla javascript.  Bottom line is that `jQuery` just doesn't play well with all of `THREE.js` and so it's absolutely best to use `document.getElementById`.  Thanks for the response!   (FYI,  had a few other questions about this same fiddle - I posted them here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/scene-within-a-scene-finer-points/23635. So if you wanna continue troubleshooting this little ditty with me, check it out. Thanks again!)

Comment: I'm not registered at the threejs forum. But Q2 is because you render the details scene only once. Listen to the orbit controls change event to render the scene (see my jsfiddle above) or put the detailsRenderer.render() call in the render loop.

Comment: Yes! I saw that! The line you added to the fiddle code: `detailsOrbitController.addEventListener('change', () => {
    detailsRenderer.render(detailsScene, detailsCamera);`   -   I copy-pasted it immediately and it worked. I forgot to thank you for that as well. Beyond that, I guess I'll also post my question from the Three.js forums here, so that other folks - such as yourself - could see it and possibly provide more answers for the community as a whole. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello again - I've got a new and totally inexplicable issue with this same scene-within-a-scene scenario that you helped me with - I posted a new question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286987/three-js-orbitcontrol-misbehaving   Would greatly appreciate if you could give your two cents!